# Boot fails to Grub Rescue "crypto.mod" not found

Tags: server, grub2, grubrescue

I have a remote server, which I have no physical access to. I rebooted the machine over the weekend and it's now refusing to boot, dumping me at the Grub rescue command (I have KVM access). When I try to run this command:

```
insmod normal
```

The error message I get is:

```
error: file '/grub/i386-pc/crypto.mod' not found.
```

Please note that I do not have physical access to the server, so I am unable to use a live CD.
Any other ideas how I can get this to boot?

Comment: Try to place **crypto.mod** into `/grub/i386-pc`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem after an update.

login to ubuntu using USB  [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Re-install the grub and you are all set.
[grub installation](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: pendrivelinux :  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

      grub installation : http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/